# How change files in :C drive on windows with python

Tags: python, windows, tkinter

I’m working in program that need to save my settings data in drives, so I put my data’s file in C drive next to the my program files. But My program can’t change them , windows needs permission to let program change files, what can I do that my program can change the data file !?

Thanks everyone

Comment: Where in the C drive? Did you try using the `localappdata` folder? Can you provide a [mre]?

Comment: I put them in programs file folder in drive C

Comment: I do not recommend it, and you may have tried this already, but if you know what you are doing, you could launch your program with administrators rights. If it is not possible, you have no other choice than saving your data files in a directory where you have write access.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just launch your program with administrators rights. It should probably solve the write/change permissions.

Comment: If you are going to be writing to the C drive, opening your program in administrator mode might be a bad idea. What happens if OP makes a mistake? That is why folders like `localappdata` exist.